# javascript setInterval not running on time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a timer method which isn't working correctly. It is supposed to display the time elapsed while on a form, but it is counting by 2's or 3's instead of once per second. What could cause this behavior and how can I fix it?

My code:

```js
function startTimer() {
  var minutes, seconds;
  
  setInterval(function () {
    if (!isPaused) {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
      
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      
      $('#TimeLabel').text("Form Time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
      
      ++timer;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

The above code displays "Form Time: 00:01" then "Form Time: 00:04" then "Form Time:00:07" ect.

Comment: `setInterval` (and `setTimeout`) are not guaranteed to be accurate in any way.  They only have to wait for a _minimum_ of the timeout you specify, and can run any time after that.  This is most noticable if the tab isn't active - browsers usually heavily throttle them in those cases.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I suppose I'll need to write a new method to subtract from the current time and calculate the elapsed time that way. Thanks

Comment: They should on the other hand not be several seconds of, generally it's just milliseconds. I think, from just quickly looking at the code, the issue is the way you're incrementing a number, and then dividing that to get the seconds etc. and you keep compounding the small errors in `setTimeout` until it becomes more and more, and eventually seconds.

Comment: While what @JamesThorpe said is undoubtedly true, your webpage would have to be *very* slow for it to be grouping 1 second intervals together when your webpage isn't in the background.

Comment: Yes - the others above are right - there's something else going on here that's delaying it to this degree.  But your comment about calculating the elapsed time is also the correct thing to be doing too.

Comment: It could be. My page is extremely heavy... it's all dynamic and we all know how bad dynamic code looks.

Comment: In case you didn't see it - @SundarSingh makes a valid point in a comment on his answer below - are you positive that `startTimer` is only being called once?

Comment: Unless the form is being loaded more than once, it should just be called one time. I will figure that out though, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of what I came up with. It uses time so as not to be dependent on the accuracy of your *setInterval*. Hope this helps!

```
function startTimer(){
        var minutes,
            seconds;

        var startTime = new Date;

        setInterval(function(){

            var currentTime = new Date;
            seconds = currentTime.getSeconds() - startTime.getSeconds();

            if(seconds < 0){
                seconds += 60;
            }else if(seconds === 0){
                minutes = currentTime.getMinutes() - startTime.getMinutes();
            }

            console.log(minutes + ':' + seconds);

        }, 100);
}
startTimer();
```

Comment: Thanks, this ended up being exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used code in console and found it is working fine there, code is :

```
  var timer =1;
  var minutes, seconds;

  setInterval(function () {

  minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
  seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  console.log("Form Time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);

  ++timer;
  }, 1000);
```

So there might be something which increases the value of timer or ensure that your function startTimer called only once.

Comment: Hope you are running startTimer just once

Comment: Your comment here could be a lot more valid than your answer - If indeed it's being called 3 times, it would explain the behaviour.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm just learning how to answer questions here as I'm new :)

Comment: We were all new once!  The problem here is that "ensure it's only being called once" is more of a comment than a proper answer, but because you don't have 50 rep yet you can't make that comment under the question itself.  Keep going - it only takes a few upvotes on some answers to get the comment everywhere privilege :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the async nature of javascript and on the fact that it runs on a single thread.

There are many articles on the web who explain how the ***event loop*** works, so, I think that isn't necessary to explain it here.

You just need to keep in mind that:
`setTimeout` or `setInterval`, or other similar instructions, will be executed at the first available time after the `delay time` passed as parameter.

So, `window.setTimeout(function() { console.log('Hello World'); }, 1000);` doesn't mean that will be executed exactly after 1000ms (1s).

It basically means wait for 100ms and when the event loop is free call the callback passed as parameter.

[further reading](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have something to do with not declaring all of your variables. When I run this version in the console, it works properly:

```js
function startTimer() {
  var minutes, seconds, isPaused = false, timer = 1;
  
  setInterval(function () {
    if (!isPaused) {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
      
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      
      console.log("Form Time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
      
      timer++;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```