# Ios 10 - Local Notification are fired late , in wrong time

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications, localnotification

Hi guys I am experiencing a strange behavior. Some of my local notifications are coming in the wrong time. In my app i have a lot of individual notifications, that have to come in customs interval during the day. For this, i schedule one notification for each interval. But some of my notification are fired later for apparently no reason.

Can anyone knows why this behavior occurs?

I am using this plugin for Ionic Cordova app https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/ios10

Edit: Here some of my code

For date manipulation i am using mommentjs lib:
http://momentjs.com/docs/

```
//for registering a single
var alertData = {
      id: self.alarme_id //This id i get from a timestamp,
      title: 'Alerta',
      badge : 1, //Using same badge
      text: moment(self.alarme_data).format('HH:mm') + ' - Está na hora de pingar o seu colírio ' + self.alarme_remedio,
      at: moment(self.alarme_data).seconds(0).toDate(),
      // every: 0,
      // sound: $ionicPlatform.isIOS ? 'www/audio/alert_ai.aif' : 'android.resource://' + myOptions.packageName + '/raw/alert',
       sound: ionic.Platform.isIOS() ? 'file://audio/notification.aiff' : 'android.resource://br.com.furia7.clinicapp.moacir/raw/alert',
      // icon: "http://icons.com/?cal_id=1",
      data: self
    };

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
          cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(alertData);
          defer.resolve(true);
        }, false);
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: And also let us know if your application is working while in background mode ?

Comment: intervals aren't spot on. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359818/javascript-setinterval-not-running-on-time

Comment: @xpereta I edited my question, for objective-c logic we have to look on plugin

Comment: @KirankumarDafda, My code dont make nothing in background. I just schedule the local notification and let the system delivery my notification